# What could the source of this ticking sound be?

Tags: road-bike, noise

I have an annoying ticking sound that I need some help with. I've read through a lot of suggestions online and two bike shops have failed to solve it.

The bike is a brand new custom build (Trek Emonda ALR frame with mostly carbon upgraded parts) with less than 500 miles on it so far. The single tick occurs only when the right pedal starts to come over the top past 12 o clock in the pedal stroke. It is louder when the bike is under more load like when riding up an incline. It occurs when I wear regular shoes and ride the bike, so it is not my cleats. It occurs when sitting or standing or when not holding the handlebars. The shop has tried swapping pedals and even reinstalled the bottom bracket. I've swapped wheels and it still happens. I recently was able to recreate the "tick" sound while sitting on the bike and pressing down on my right pedal while holding the front brake to resist some forward movement. It doesn't happen if I do this and use the back brake or left pedal instead. It also doesn't seem to be an issue until a few minutes into a ride but I'm not sure what that could mean. Any suggestions would be great as to what this could be

Comment: Did you but this bike from a local bike shop. Such shops, especially the the Trek-owned store, typically will be very helpful with new bikes such as this.

Comment: Defective frame maybe. I've encountered forks that were exchanged by a big manufacturer due to clicking. They were safe but made a little noise while riding.

Comment: I would check if bottom headset bearing is clean. On my MTB, when sand gets into BB and headset, flexing of crankset and fork while pedaling creates clicks all over. I heard that precise machining of wheel hubs might create micro movement and clicking noise under load. Or as a @Noise said, probably defective frame/fork.

Comment: I feel guilty of always pulling my old thread out when somebody asks this question, but here we go - https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/89316/bb386-bottom-bracket-clicking-noise-once-per-rotation - in my case, I had it as creaks and clicking, what temporarily helped was my LBS taking out and greasing the BB but recently, it tends to come back at lower temperatures and stays away when it is warm. Please note my bike is carbon and my best guess is that the BB hole isn't perfectly round but I'm not sure if I want to go down the route of forcing my LBS to sand it or just live with it.

Comment: @DoNuT Welcome to press-fit bottom brackets...  Funny how [it's all but impossible to find out what bottom bracket the Trek Emonda ALR actually uses](https://www.trekbikes.com/us/en_US/bikes/road-bikes/performance-road-bikes/%C3%A9monda/%C3%A9monda-alr/c/B212/).  It's almost as if they know press-fit bottom brackets are NOT a selling point.  It's buried in the description instead of clearly spelled out in the specs...

Comment: Call me crazy but I just dug out this [link](https://www.trekbikes.com/at/de_AT/bikes/rennr%C3%A4der/performance-rennr%C3%A4der/%C3%A9monda/%C3%A9monda-alr/%C3%A9monda-alr-6/p/33077/) from my browser history 3 hours ago and it now it is a 404, I swear the page for the ALR 6 listed a Shimano BB71 and that's why I went with Pressfit. If OP has a 2023 model with T47, he can be glad about it. ;)

Comment: @DoNuT Yep the bottom bracket is a Praxis T47

Comment: OK that narrows it down a bit, did you check the chainring bolts are properly tightened? It is yet another shot in the dark, though ....

Comment: @DoNuT I figured the shops would have but I will try to check.

Comment: Here's the link to the [BB found on the new Emondas](https://www.trekbikes.com/us/en_US/equipment/cycling-components/bike-bottom-brackets/praxis-shimano-t47-inboard-bottom-bracket/p/593089/).  This page came from a hyperlink on the specs page of the Emondas ALR.  It's a T47 threaded BB.